# Filtering based on Key Value in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in my database/dataframe which is a key value pair. I want to filter data based on certain value.
Say only those rows with value 'DDD' for the key 'ddd'.
How can this be achived in spark/spark sql?

```
"{'aaa': 'AAA', 'bbb': 'BBB', 'ccc': 'CCC', 'ddd': 'DDD', 'eee': 'EEE', 'fff': 'FFF', 'ggg': 'GGG'}"
 "{'aaa': 'AAA1', 'bbb': 'BBB1', 'ccc': 'CCC1', 'ddd': 'DDD1', 'eee': 'EEE1', 'fff': 'FFF1', 'ggg': 'GGG1'}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it like below using filter function

```
     DataFrame inputDf= //read from database

     DataFrame filteredDf=inputDf.filter("ddd='DDD'");
```

Comment: I got this working with the below approach. Anything better that i can use?val filteredRdd = textFileDF.map(line => line.getAs[String]("colname")).filter(line => line.contains("ddd':'DDD"))

Comment: @SandeepShetty: That is DF approach and yours is rdd approach. both are better if they are working :-)